# yum in rhel5.1 through internet

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rhel

i am using redhat 5.1 versions .i need the rpm that automatically download from internet 
similar to centos and  ubuntu. see i have an old gcc. compiler i want to download the latest 
version compatible to my rhel 5.1 with this yum utility.please suggest 
sunil

Comment: This question should be on serverfault.com and not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade the version of yum you are using (the version in RHEL-5.2 might be enough, but 5.4+ would be better) you can run:

yum --showduplicates list gcc

...and then install/upgrade/downgrade to a specific version. If the version you want isn't available in RHEL, then I'd seriously caution against using it ... however even then you should be able to download the rpm manually and use "yum downgrade gcc-blah.rpm" (or install/etc) to move to it.